# Replace row data in file

Tags: python, replace, open-with

I have two files: `file1`, `file2`.

In `file1` I have lines with data that I'm parsing into `list1` with skipping empty rows and making an elements lowercase:

**file1:**

```
dATa02
datA03

dAta04
```

```
with open('file1', 'r') as f:
    list1 = [l.lower() for l in (line.strip() for line in f) if l]
```

As a result, I get a data list `list1`: `[ 'data02', 'data03', 'data04' ]`

In `file2` I have a row: `if [data] in [ "data01", "data02", "data03" ] {` which constantly start with `if [data] in`

**file2:**

```
#somedata
if [data] in [ "data01", "data02", "data03" ] {
#somedate
```

I'm using regular expression for parsing data list:

```
import re
with open('/file2', 'r+') as f:
    for l in f:
        l_s = row.strip()
        if 'if [data] in ' in row_s:
            data1 = re.findall('"(.\w+)\"*', l_s)
            print(data1)
```

As a result I get another data list `list2`: `[ 'data01', 'data02', 'data03' ]`

After getting two lists, I perform a comparison:

```
added = set(list1) - set(list2) #data04
deleted = set(list2) - set(list1) #data01
```

The question is: How to replace `list2` from `file2` to `list1` from `file1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by code below:

```
if list1 == list2:
    print("Nothing changed...")
else:
    print("Found changes:")
    added_set = set(list1) - set(list2)
    deleted_set = set(list2) - set(list1)
    if added_set:
        print(f"New env: {added_set}")
    if deleted_set:
        print(f"Old env: {deleted_set}")

    env_new_str = (str(env_new).replace("'", '"'))
    env_prod_str = (str(env_prod).replace("'", '"'))

    try:
        s = open("file2").read()
        s = s.replace(env_prod_str, env_new_str)

        f = open("file2", 'w')
        f.write(s)
        print("Changed...")
    finally:
        f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can generate the list in file2 based on file1?

File 2 would look like this:

```
#somedata
with open('file1', 'r') as f:
    list1 = [l.lower() for l in (line.strip() for line in f) if l]

if [data] in list1 {
#somedate
```

Comment: I can't insert into ```file2``` other code, cuz it's a configuration file for an application.